# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: angularjs, jpa, spring-boot, arraylist, jackson

Usando angular, não estou conseguindo inserir um array de gêneros na propriedade Genero que está no objeto Manga.

Usando postman para inserir o array de Generos na API /manga, ficaria assim.

```
    {
    "nome": "BORUTO",
    "status": "COMPLETO",
    "dataLancado": "2015",
    "genero" : [{"id":1, "nome":"TERROR"},{"id":"2", "nome":"ACAO"}]
   }
```

[Postman api do manga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYPzF.png)

Como extrair Array de JSON para dentro de um atributo do tipo List de um objeto?Quero pegar os generos TERROR,ACAO e salvar na propriedade Genero que está no objeto Manga.

Tentei da seguinte forma usando checkbox mas recebi um erro.

**index.html**

```
   <label ng-repeat="genero in generolist ">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selected.generos" checklist-value="genero" ng-model="manga.genero[selected.generos.id]"/> {{genero.nome}}
     </label>
     <pre>{{selected.generos|json}}</pre>     

    <input type="button" value="Salvar" ng-click="salvarMangas()"/>
```

**Erro.**

```
2017-11-20 13:18:07.146  WARN 4324 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@659aad31; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.mangastech.model.MangasEntity["genero"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@659aad31; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.mangastech.model.MangasEntity["genero"])
2017-11-20 13:18:07.147  WARN 4324 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@659aad31; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.mangastech.model.MangasEntity["genero"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@659aad31; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.mangastech.model.MangasEntity["genero"])
```

**mangas-controller.js**

```
        $scope.mangas = [];
        $scope.manga = {};
        $scope.generolist = [
                {id:1, nome: 'TERROR'}
        ];

        $scope.selected = {
                generos : []
        };

        $scope.salvarMangas= function() {
            $http({
                  method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:8080/manga',data:$scope.manga})
                  .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.mangas.push(response.data);
                     /*carregarClientes();

                      $scope.manga={};*/

                  }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    console.log(response.status);
                  });
            };
```

**MangasController em java.**

```
//Cadastra novo Manga
    @RequestMapping(value="/manga", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public MangasEntity cadastrarManga(@Valid @RequestBody MangasEntity manga){
        return mangaRepository.save(manga);
    }
```

**MangasEntity.class**

```
public class MangasEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private  Status status;
    private int dataLancado;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("manga")  
    private  AutorEntity autor;

    private List<GenerosEntity> genero = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="nome")
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="status")
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }


    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column
    public int getDataLancado() {
        return dataLancado;
    }

    public void setDataLancado(int dataLancado) {
        this.dataLancado = dataLancado;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="mangas_autor",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="manga_id",referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="autor_id",referencedColumnName="id"))

    public AutorEntity getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(AutorEntity autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }


    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = GenerosEntity.class)
    @JoinTable(name="mangas_generos", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="manga_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="genero_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    )

    public List<GenerosEntity> getGenero() {
        return this.genero;
    }


    public void setGenero(List<GenerosEntity> genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public MangasEntity() {
        super();
    }


    public MangasEntity(Long id, String nome, Status status, int dataLancado, AutorEntity autor,
            List<GenerosEntity> genero) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.status = status;
        this.dataLancado = dataLancado;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public MangasEntity(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**GenerosEntity.class**

```
public class GenerosEntity implements Serializable {    


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String nome;

    @JsonIgnore
    private List<MangasEntity> manga  ;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="nome")
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="genero", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
    public List<MangasEntity> getManga() {
        return manga;
    }

    public void setManga(List<MangasEntity> manga) {
        this.manga = manga;
    }

    public GenerosEntity() {

    }

    public GenerosEntity(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a origem do erro seja o formato do objeto que você está enviando para API. Fiz um código de exemplo onde primeiro são obtidos todos os **GÊNEROS** para carregar a lista de checkboxes, em seguida é feito a obtenção do **MANGA** a ser editado para então percorrer a lista de gêneros marcando os já vinculados ao manga e a cada change dos checkboxes a lista de gêneros do manga em edição será atualizada.

**controller.js**

```
.controller('indexController',['$scope','$filter', function($scope, $filter){
    var vm = this;
    vm.Model={};

    //Aqui vem a chamada da API dos generos
    vm.Model.Generos=[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "TERROR"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "ACAO"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nome": "AVENTURA"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "ROMANCE"
        }
    ];
    //no sucesso da requisição ele chama o manga

    //Aqui vem API de obter o Manga que preencherá o item par edição
    vm.Model.Manga = {
        "nome": "BORUTO",
        "status": "COMPLETO",
        "dataLancado": "2015",
        "genero" : [{"id":1, "nome":"TERROR"},{"id":"2", "nome":"ACAO"}]
    };

    //no then do manga ele executa e atualiza a lista de generos
    vm.Load= function (){
        if (vm.Model.Manga.genero && vm.Model.Generos) {
            angular.forEach(vm.Model.Generos, function(_genero, i){
                _genero.Selecionado = $filter('filter')(vm.Model.Manga.genero,{id:_genero.id}).length > 0 ;         
            });
        };
    }
    vm.Load();

    //função após mudar os checkboxes
    vm.Selecionar = function () {
        vm.Model.Manga.genero = $filter('filter')(vm.Model.Generos,{Selecionado: true});
    }

}]);
```

**view.html**

```
<legend>Form title</legend>
<hr/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Nome</label>
    <input ng-model="vm.Model.Manga.nome" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Status</label>
    <input ng-model="vm.Model.Manga.status" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="_genero in vm.Model.Generos">
         <label>
             <input ng-model="_genero.Selecionado"
                    ng-change="vm.Selecionar()"
                    type="checkbox" />
             <span ng-bind="_genero.nome"></span>                       
         </label>
     </li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.